# Тамариск или тамарикс?

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу разобраться с этим растением. По-латыни пишется tamarix, а по-русски пишут то "тамарикс", то "тамариск". А как все-таки правильно? Или можно и так, и так?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и так, и так. Вот например, [ссылка](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F2%E0%EC%E0%F0%E8%F1%EA&all=x), на словарь Лопатина